# ReadOnlyObservableCollection shows duplicate values

Tags: xamarin.forms, dynamic-data

I am having trouble with my `CollectionView` which is showing duplicates objects each time I display the page, meaning the first time I will have 1 object (which is normal), but if I navigate and return to that page it will duplicate the same object, so I get it twice, then thrice ..etc...

Below is the code in the `constructor` of the ViewModel of my page:

```
            Cache
            .AutoRefresh(x => x.Code)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Bind(out _list)
            .DisposeMany();
```

`_list` is a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<AddressViewModel>`

`Cache` is `IObservable<IchangeSet<AddressModel, string>>` obtained from a `GetAllObjects` from `Akavache` cache.

```
                _blobCache
                .GetAllObjects<AddressModel>()
                .ToObservableChangeSet(t => t.Code)
                .AsObservableCache()
                .Connect();
```

The binding to my `CollectionView` is

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.List, v => v.addressList.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(disposables);
```

Thank you for any help or hint

**UPDATE**

The duplicating behaviour happens ONLY when navigating between tabs, if I push a new page and go back I find again 1 object which is the intended behaviour.

Here is the code setting the BindingContext of the page

In code behind of the `TabbedPage`

```
public partial class MainTabbedPage : ReactiveTabbedPage<MainViewModel>
    {
        public MainTabbedPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.WhenActivated(
                disposables =>
                {
                    this
                        .OneWayBind(this.ViewModel, x => x.AddressVm, x => x.addressView.ViewModel)
                        .DisposeWith(disposables);
                    //other tabs...
                });
        }
    }
```

In the `MainViewModel`

```
        public AddressViewModel AddressVm => new AddressViewModel(HostScreen);

        public MainViewModel(IScreen hostScreen) : base(hostScreen)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Well, I have a feeling you are assigning data to your `ObservableCollection` in the OnAppearing method which is basically getting called over and over, in turn, adding duplicate data! But if that is not the case we need to see all the code related to this i.e. xaml.cs and VM code otherwise we would just be speculating!!!

Comment: Set the breakpoint at the line where you assign your data and see how many times it gets called

Comment: @apex39 The code with `Bind(out _list)` is in the constructor of the ViewModel of the page, and yes it is called each time the view is showing.

Comment: @FreakyAli See my above comment to apex39, it is not in OnAppearing but in the constructor of the ViewModel and gets called each time the view is on screen. What did I miss, where to put such a code if I cannot put in in my ViewModel?

Comment: How come your ViewModel's constructor called multiple times? I mean isn't the point of a constructor just being called once?

Comment: @FreakyAli You are right this is what I thought too, however, putting a break point shows me it is called. It is the first tab of a TabbedPage and navigating between tabs shows this strange behaviour of constructor called each time (hence duplication). When I open a new page by selecting an item in this collection view and go back, items are not duplicated.

Comment: You would better post the  code about setting the binding context  in page.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It is in the code behind not in the page `this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.List, v => v.addressList.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(disposables);`

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT See my update please

Comment: `this.WhenActivated` is a problem, because _WhenActivated allows you to register a Func to be called when a View is Activated._ Try to achieve wanted behaviour in `OnBindingContextChanged()` by overriding it.

Comment: I doubt that constructor gets called many times.`this.WhenActivated` is triggered

Comment: Yep, agree with @apex39 this.WhenActivated is called every time your view gets activated

Comment: Please share how you fixed it.